# remove lines after second pattern sed

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm looking to trim a file and I need to remove everything after the second match (and everything before the first match).

For example Say I have this text:

```
xxx xxx
yyy yyy
New USB device found
xxx xxx
yyy yyy
zzz zzz
New USB device found
xxx xxx
yyy yyy
```

If I use the following `sed` command :

```
sed -i '1,/New USB device found/d' <FILE>
```

this removes everything before the first match. which is great:

```
New USB device found
xxx xxx
yyy yyy
zzz zzz
New USB device found
xxx xxx
yyy yyy
```

But I'm only 1/2 way there, now I want to remove everything after the 2nd match to get this result:

```
New USB device found
xxx xxx
yyy yyy
zzz zzz
```

Hence just the data for the first device.

Comment: A real low grade method would be to just keep count in a loop.    cat $CHUNK
  echo "STARTING"
  c=0
  while read aline; do
   if [ "$(echo ${aline}|grep 'New USB device found')" ] ;then
    (( c += 1 ))
   fi
   [[ $c -lt 2 ]] && echo "out: $aline"
  done < ${CHUNK}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This awk one-liner should give what you want:

```
awk '/New USB device found/{p++}p==1' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  awk '/New USB device found/{p++}p==1' file
    New USB device found
    xxx xxx
    yyy yyy
    zzz zzz
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me!    
  awk '/New USB device found/{p++}p==1' ${CHUNK} > ${TMPFILE}

Answer (score 2):

If you have `GNU awk` then:

```
$ awk 'NR==2{print RS,$0}' RS='New USB device found' file
New USB device found 
xxx xxx
yyy yyy
zzz zzz
```

Just compare the record number you want to print against `NR`. This makes printing the 112th record as easy as print the 4th record just by changing `NR==2` to `NR==112` or `NR==4`.

Comment: Actually, if he wants the 112th record, he'd have to use NR==113

Comment: @glennjackman look at the OP sample data again. The record comes before the separator so in fact the 112th record really is when `NR==112` unless the OP omitted the first record separator mistakenly.

Comment: I know exactly what you're saying, but I think the OP is thinking that the "first wanted block" is the text *following* the first RS

Comment: @glennjackman that is just semantics, you can want all you like but the *"first wanted block"* is still the nth block after n-1 record separators.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sed solution:

```
sed -i '1,/New USB device found/d; /New USB device found/,$d' <FILE>
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `sed -i '1,/^New/d;/^New/,$d'`

Comment: This one deletes also the first pattern.

Comment: The 1st half of OP's solution also deletes the 1st pattern, so I'm assuming that's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

using sed:

```
sed -n '/New/{:a;p;n; /New/!ba}' input
```